Reject H0 on Friedman test but fail to reject in any pairwise wilcoxin test
I am currently working compare auroc of different models, and I did Friedman test first and then Pairwise Wilcoxon test to see difference.
The test data: data link
The data was generated with SVM, Random Forest, XGBoost tested on 3 repeats stratified 10-fold.
here is my r code:
variables <- c("model_name", "n_pcs", "n_snps","treatment")

# Create 'treatment' variable if not already done
auc$treatment <- with(auc, paste(model_name, n_pcs, n_snps, sep = "_"))

# Load required library
library(RColorBrewer)

# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(multcompView)

# Loop through variables, perform Friedman tests, calculate group labels, and plot
results <- lapply(variables, function(var) {
  # Create matrix: rows = observations, columns = groups (levels of the variable)
  groups <- unique(auc[[var]])
  Sample <- sapply(groups, function(g) auc$roc_auc[auc[[var]] == g])
  y <- auc$roc_auc
  
  # Perform Friedman test
  friedman_result <- friedman.test(Sample)
  
  # Print Friedman test result
  cat("Friedman test for", var, "\n")
  print(friedman_result)
  cat("\n")
  
  # Pairwise Wilcoxon signed-rank test with Bonferroni adjustment
  p_values <- pairwise.wilcox.test(y, auc[[var]], p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", exact = FALSE)$p.value
  print(p_values)
  
  # Create significance matrix
  sig_matrix <- matrix(1, nrow = length(groups), ncol = length(groups))
  rownames(sig_matrix) <- colnames(sig_matrix) <- groups
  
  # Populate the matrix with adjusted p-values
  for (i in 1:nrow(p_values)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(p_values)) {
      if (!is.na(p_values[i, j])) {
        sig_matrix[i+1, j] <- p_values[i, j]
        sig_matrix[j, i+1] <- p_values[i, j]
      }
    }
  }
  
  print(sig_matrix)
  
  # Assign group labels
  group_labels <- multcompLetters(sig_matrix, threshold = 0.05)$Letters
  
  # Calculate medians for each group
  medians <- tapply(auc$roc_auc, auc[[var]], median, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  # Prepare data for ggplot
  plot_data <- data.frame(
    roc_auc = y,
    group = factor(auc[[var]], levels = groups)
  )
  label_data <- data.frame(
    group = names(group_labels),
    labels = group_labels,
    y = 1.1  # Position for group labels above the plot
  )
  median_data <- data.frame(
    group = names(medians),
    medians = medians
  )
  
  # Create the ggplot boxplot
  p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = group, y = roc_auc)) +
    geom_boxplot(fill = "#EBEBEB", color = "black", width = 0.6, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +  # Grey-colored boxes with black borders
    theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
    geom_text(data = median_data, aes(x = group, y = medians + 0.05, label = round(medians, 2)),
              color = "red", size = 3) +  # Add median values
    geom_text(data = label_data, aes(x = group, y = y, label = labels),
              color = "blue", size = 4) +  # Add group labels
    labs(title = paste("Friedman Test with Pairwise Wilcoxon:", var),
         x = ifelse(var == "treatment", "", var),  # Remove x-label for 'treatment'
         y = "AUROC") +
    ylim(0, 1.2)   # Set y-axis limits
  
  if (var == "treatment") {
    p <- p + theme(
      plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10),  # Add margins around the plot
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 8),  # Rotate x-axis labels
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10),  # Adjust x-axis title size
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10)   # Adjust y-axis title size
    )
  } else {
    p <- p + theme(
      plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10),  # Add margins around the plot
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10),  # Adjust x-axis title size
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10)   # Adjust y-axis title size
    )
  }
  
  # Print the plot
  print(p)
  
  # Return test results and group labels
  list(test_result = friedman_result, p_values = p_values, group_labels = group_labels)
})

And strange result:
Friedman chi-squared = 23.952, df = 3, p-value = 2.556e-05
                MLP RandomForest       SVM
RandomForest 0.6986949           NA        NA
SVM          0.4126711    1.0000000        NA
XGBoost      1.0000000    0.4126711 0.1787532

Did I write a wrong code, or it is relative rare but possible case?
Thanks~

(i) search here on your keywords (e.g. Friedman post hoc Wilcoxon, Friedman post hoc signed rank etc - but be sure to spell all the names correctly) to find comments and or answers explaining that the signed rank test does not correspond to the Friedman, and (ii) search here on post hoc tests more generally to find out that even when tests do correspond, it's generally the case that you can get non-rejection in post hocs after a rejection in the omnibus test. This is typically unavoidable without introducing other issues people tend to see as undesirable.

The first issue is discussed here or here. The second issue can occur even with ordinary ANOVA; in part it's a consequence of the fact that omnibus acceptance regions and the union of the pairwise-comparison acceptance regions don't coincide.

@Glen_b Thanks, it helps a lot
